# Boost Program Options Config File

Tags: c++, xml, boost

I looked through the boost documentation and couldn't get an answer.

Does program_options support a configuration file stored in XML format or do I need to use property_tree for the file?

Reason I ask is because my program also has command line options, so I'm already using program_options.

Comment: No, XML configuration files are not supported.

Comment: Thanks for the response!  That's what I figured, but the documentation doesn't show any details regarding the config file format.

Comment: You can use boost serialization to "deserialise" your config file from XML. This should get you close to the same thing without using another library.